# c# datatable datatype to UTF32

Tags: c#, datatable, type-conversion, utf-32

I have a challenging problem. I'm currently getting the datatable from SQL which has EM-DASH and other special characters that the datatable does not support unless if the type is in UTF32. Is there a way to convert the datatype from string to UTF32?

There is a function to FillDataTable which reads the Query and fills the table from SQL note that all columns are string format. This is what i have done so far:

```
var dt = FillDataTable(query).Copy();
DataTable dtClone = table.Clone();
dtClone.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(System.Text.UTF32Encoding);
dtClone.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(System.Text.UTF32Encoding);
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
dtClone.ImportRow(r);
```

However this does not work. Is there a way to do this so that it keeps the string in tack? Otherwise the em-dash becomes a hidden symbol since it's using UTF8.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Em-dash (U+2014) is easily representable in UTF-8 (all Unicode characters are) and it's even in the BMP. What *exactly* are you observing?

Comment: "four key factors  country allocation" -- This is how it comes when it's suppose to be "four key factors – country allocation"

Comment: And how exactly are you determining that? Have you examined the string in the debugger, for example? I don't see why you think using a different encoding would help.

Comment: Yeah so in that string there is a special coding because when i take the datatable and copy into excel for example the character (which is not visible) comes up like an upsidedown questionmark. I believe if the datetype of the datatable was UTF-32 this should fix the problem. My assumption is that it switches the character from original one to a special one - when i try to do a search by that column with the same string it does not find it .. i'll have to use the upsidedown question mark - This is a little confusing to explain let me know if you are still confused.

Comment: Yes, I'm very confused as to where you think UTF-32 comes into this... and I definitely wouldn't start relying on "what happens when you paste it into Excel" as a good indication of what's going on. You should look at the value carefully in the debugger.

Comment: Mmm.. Fair enough. Heres a new question on SQL column 1 has this field "factors – country" however when i move that column 1 into datatable in c# it comes out like this "factors  country"  in the debugger console how can i fix that?

Comment: Well start by putting that into the question, then give details of what *exactly* you mean by "it comes out like this". Also see if you see the same behaviour when you read the value using `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: posted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054668/c-sharp-read-sql-table-with-special-characters-into-dataset thanks

Comment: Why have you asked a *new* question rather than editing the existing one? I note the new question still doesn't explain how you're viewing the data, either...

Comment: oh shoot lol .. i thought you wanted me to ask another one. Basically the data will be stored in a DataSet (this is a common dll library in this project) so how they use the dataset is up to each project that uses this dll. ie. sometimes it's used to write to excel (data dump) sometimes used to compare if that table has certain string in the dataset .. pull those strings and write to excel/ another datatable which gets loaded into sql again etc.

Comment: Forget Excel. For now, you should be trying to narrow down the problem as much as possible, and explain in detail how you're diagnosing it, in the question itself rather than comments.

Comment: updated to the best i could. I guess noone has a solution to this :(

Comment: I don't believe that's the best you could, really. You still haven't said in the question how you're looking at the results, or where you think UTF-32 comes in, or what the exact data type is in the server side (with collation etc). But I agree that without more information, it's unlikely that you'll be able to get more help.